# Unlock Swipe Pattern From Differnent Phones.?

Tags: android, adb, unlock

Hello I would like to know the adb command to unlock the swipe lock in any android phone using some commands irrespective of the device.
 Thank You

Comment: check this ref: https://github.com/mattwilson1024/android-pattern-unlock

Comment: @DaminiMehra I don't have any pattern lock.i just need to automatically swipe the screen in any of the 4 directions(which is unknown) irrespective of the device!

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell su 0 service call window 49` would call `WindowManager.dismissKeyguard()` in Android 5.1+